# How to interpret this Iteration over list of tuples using key defined as a function using 'lambda'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tuples, iteration, key

I used lasso regression algorithm over crime dateset. After training and testing of the model, in order to display the non-zero coefficients the fallowing code is used:

```
for e in sorted (list(zip(list(X_crime), linlasso.coef_)),
            key = lambda e: -abs(e[1])):
    if e[1] != 0:
        print('\t{}, {:.3f}'.format(e[0], e[1]))
```

I am not getting clarity about how this code is working!!
I know its a iteration and '**e**' is the key of the tuples also the index for running the loop.
The iteration is done over the list of tuples, i want to know more about the key declaration in code.
especially this line.

```
            key = lambda e: -abs(e[1]))
```

how to interpret this??
Is it a range declaration??
where can i find python example codes where this kind off iteration are implemented??
what is its significance??

Comment: Do you understand how lambdas work in general? Did you try reading the documentation for `sorted`?

Comment: Thanks, now i got an idea !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know ... `e` is ... also the index for running the loop

`e` is not an index it is the *current* item of the sequence being iterated.

```
key = lambda e: -abs(e[1]))
```

The lambda function *extracts* the second item from `e`, passes it to `abs`, *multiplies* by minus one and returns the result.

Not knowing what `abs` is or what your data values are I made them up for illustration.

```
>>> X_crime = [3,1,2]
>>> linlasso_coef_ = [9,10,11]

>>> def abs(n):
...    return n*n
```

Breaking down the loop and the lambda:

You are iterating over a list of sorted tuples.

```
>>> list(zip(list(X_crime), linlasso_coef_))
[(3, 9), (1, 10), (2, 11)]
>>> sorted(list(zip(list(X_crime), linlasso_coef_)))
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 9)]
```

On the first iteration `e` is `(1,10)`.

```
>>> 
>>> e = (1,10)
>>> e[1]
10
>>> abs(e[1])
100
>>> -abs(e[1])
-100
```

[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) creates a *throwaway* function.

```
>>> lambda e: -abs(e[1])
<function <lambda> at 0x00000213E08538B0>
```

The function is assigned to the name `key`

```
>>> key = lambda e: -abs(e[1])
>>> key
<function <lambda> at 0x00000213E0853F70>
```

For use later (?)

```
>>> key(e)
-100
>>>
```

---

> what is its significance??

Not enough information for anyone to comment adequately but presumably `key` is being used later in the loop for some type of *analysis*(?).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation!! It was very informative!!